# Special TABLE sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting

I have a two column TABLE from a previous query like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| Id_no1 | Id_no2 |
+--------+--------+
|  1     |    2   |
|  1     |    2   |
|  1     |    3   |
|  1     |    5   |
|  2     |    1   |
|  2     |    3   |
|  2     |    3   |
|  2     |    5   |
|  3     |    1   |
|  3     |    2   |
+--------+--------+
```

The TABLE is ORDER BY Id_no1, Id_no2

I want Id_no1 and Id_no2 to be paired like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| Id_no1 | Id_no2 |
+--------+--------+
|  1     |    2   |
|  1     |    2   |
|  2     |    1   |
|        |        |
|  1     |    3   |
|  3     |    1   |
|        |        |
|  1     |    5   |
|        |        |
|  2     |    3   |
|  2     |    3   |
|  3     |    2   |
|        |        |
|  2     |    5   |
+--------+--------+
```

Id_no1 and Id_no2 are shops, sender and recipient. I want to group exchange between all shops.

Comment: Please learn to format your posts. You already posted over 30.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the 4 spaces for the table. I was editing when you did it yourself.

Comment: It is hard to see a pattern here. Is there a logic why you need it to look like this?

Comment: @ArthurRey If you tell us the rules for the logic, we might be able to help you. Otherwise, just as TheProvost said, it's hard to see a pattern.

Comment: Id_no1 and Id_no2 are shops, sender and recipient. I want to group exchange between all shops.

Comment: I wrote, rewrote, and edited a long paragraph trying to explain the fact that if you post a badly-explained question, you'll just end up frustrating the people who are otherwise perfectly happy to help you out.  I even considered not posting the code that (I think) will answer your question, solely because I didn't want to encourage you to post this kind of question in the future. Please, PLEASE learn to give requirements that someone else can understand; read your post from the viewpoint of someone who has never seen your data, met your business users, or understood what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is *apparently* to sort your data in order of the parties involved.  To do that, you are trying to sort first by the lowest party involved (Ascending), then by the highest party involved (also Ascending).

To get this done, I wrote the following: this gives an output in the order you've shown, and will work ... assuming my wild guess is remotely connected to your question.

```
/* Sample Data */

    WITH Table1 AS 
      (
        SELECT ID_No1, ID_No2
        FROM 
          ( VALUES 
            (1,2),
            (1,2),
            (1,3),
            (1,5),
            (2,1),
            (2,3),
            (2,3),
            (2,5),
            (3,1),
            (3,2)
          ) AS VALUE(ID_No1, ID_No2)
      )
/* Query */
    SELECT ID_No1, ID_No2
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
            *,
            CASE WHEN ID_No1 > ID_No2 THEN ID_No1 ELSE ID_No2 END AS MaxParty,
            CASE WHEN ID_No1 < ID_No2 THEN ID_No1 ELSE ID_No2 END AS MinParty
        FROM Table1
      ) arr
    ORDER BY MinParty, MaxParty, ID_No1
```

Answer (score 3):

May be this will help:

```
select * from mytab 
order by case when id_no1 < id_no2 then id_no1 else id_no2 end, 
         case when id_no2 > id_no1 then id_no2 else id_no1 end;
```

= order by min(col1, col2), max(col1, col2)

Comment: Doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: @Arthur Rey Now it's clear from the comments that there is a hierarchy. You'd better update your question. My answer follows your: "Try to set BA under AB, then CA under AC, etc."

Comment: @Arthur Rey No, it's not a hierarchy. My query should sort the data like you want. As I understand you want the pairs like (a,b) and (b,a) follow each other. But the query doesn't insert "spaces" between "groups".